# Hamburger menu icons - Recent trend of moving away from three full-width lines to having two full-width lines and a shortened line?

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons, icons

Some examples in various iOS apps:

1. US Bank[image: US Bank]
2. RentCafe [image]
3. Uber [image]

The first two kinda reminds me of the icon for aligning text justified left.

I'm quite curious about the reason for this change. I couldn't really find anything about it online. Could someone provide some insight and perhaps some online resources that talk about this?

Comment: I suspect somebody thought it would 'modernise' their interface and others have copied them. It now looks like a signal strength meter to me. ( showing about 80% signal )

Comment: The lines of the icon are a visual representation of the items in the menu that it opens up. Lines of different lengths might be more realistic but I agree that it's probably a UI trend that is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no reason beyond the evolution of the design itself.

This is what I think about usability in terms of design:

**Asymmetry**: It's well known that asymmetry is perceptually more unsettling, thus offering greater visual impact.

**Spaciousness**: The hamburger menu is used more frequently on small screens where saving space is a fundamental premise. Although the width of the icon and the thickness of each line may be the same, the difference in the length of the lines gives the feeling of spaciousness to the area where it is located.

[image]

---

A simple test in Google image search:

### Hamburger Menu Icon

[image]

### Modern Hamburger Menu Icon

[image]

Comment: Asymmetry on psychological impact can be a powerful reason for evolution in this design usage.